# Strange identicon

Tags: bug

For two days I've been meeting a strange identicon in place of the true one. This is about my own profile, and also about some other people profile. The identicon is this
[image]

I see my posts now "signed" with it. I have to click and go to my profile to see the original identicon
[image]

Same is for some other users. A snapshot of the questions page dated Sep 28, 12:00. Note Marko's alien identicon. It is not the one found on his profile.
[image]

What has happened to the site or my computer?

Comment: It's the [Gravatar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravatar) logo - presumably this is used as a default when your own identicon can't be found for some reason. I can see your usual identicon in this & other posts; perhaps try clearing your browser cache.